# Subversion Repository Location using Zend Studio

Tags: apache, svn, ssh, zend-studio

I'm trying to find the correct repository location to connect to my SVN project on the server via IP address using Zend Studio 9 for the first time.

I have setup the repository in `/var/www/accountname/rep` and the project in `/var/www/accountname/web`.

Zend however requires an `http://` location for the repository location, where I would otherwise connect via:

```
svn ls svn+ssh://root@xx.xxx.xxx.xx/var/www/accountname/web
```

*Note: I am not using a domain with this IP address, and /var/www/accountname/web/httpdocs is the public html folder.*

If I use `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/var/www/accountname/web` as the repository location though, putting in User and Password details, I get the error:

```
svn: PROPFIND of /var/www/accountname/web 405 Method Not Allowed
```

Would anyone be able to advise me on what format of repository url location/how I could use to set this connection up in Zend please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem out in the end; I was able to submit a url in Zend in the format

`svn+ssh://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/var/www/accountname/rep`

*I will leave this question here in case other users have the same issue.*

Cheers,